# Why is $\deg h(x) \leq g$ required for hyperelliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have been reading on hyperelliptic curve related resources e.g. [this](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/nitin/courses/WS2010-ref4.pdf), and they define a hyperelliptic curve as $y^2 + h(x)y = f(x)$, where $2g + 1 \leq \deg f \leq 2g + 2$ and $\deg h(x) \leq g$ (or $g + 1$ when $\deg f = 2g + 2$). My question is why is the second requirement needed? Is the curve $H: y^2 + (x^{15} + 1)y = x^5$ not a genus-$2$ hyperelliptic curve anymore?

Also, I am interested in computing on the Jacobian of this curve $J(H)$. The standard method is to use Cantor's addition algorithm to add divisors, but that again requires $\deg h \leq g$, and produces incorrect results otherwise. Are there any resources on how to do this correctly in the case above.

Comment: If you can divide by 2, you can complete the square and transform the equation to $y^2=k(x)$ with $k(x)= f(x) + h(x)^2/4$. The degree of $k$ would be too large if the inequality is not satisfied (that is, if $k$ is square-free).

Comment: @user8268 that looks like an answer to me - please record it as such below.

Comment: I see, so it'll be a genus $14$ curve in my case, that's cool.